# Is it possible to develop for iOS10 and deploy to a personal iPad for testing without a developer account?

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, xcode

I know that there is one way to do this with [XCODE 7](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206123/xcode-7-develop-for-ios-without-developer-account), however this doesn't seem to be working for me, possibly because I'm on iOS10? I have an app that I'd like to deploy on to my iPad before I decide to sign up for a developer account. Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a developer account but you do need a Mac.  These points are taken from [this blog](http://blog.ionic.io/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/):

### In order to take advantage of this, you’ll need three things:

1. Xcode 7
2. iOS 9 (minimum)
3. A free Apple ID

### To start, you’ll need to set up a provisioning profile to code sign your apps:

1. Open Xode preferences (Xcode > Preferences…)
2. Click the ‘Accounts’ tab
3. Login with your Apple ID (+ > Add Apple ID…)
4. Once you’ve successfully logged in, a new ‘Personal Team’ with the role ‘Free’ will appear beneath your Apple ID.

   [image]

There's a few more details that you can view on that site.

Comment: I tried this with my iPad and Mac and was able to add the AppleID successfully. However, I was unable to deploy to my iPad, I received a warning "Could not find developer disk image" and it did not let me proceed further. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34648168/5451769) comment seems to suggest that it is not possible to do with XCODE7, since my iPad is on iOS10. Any thoughts? Does this work with XCODE8?   I won't be able to test this right now unfortunately, since it looks like I have to upgrade my operating system to download the latest XCODE8.1