# Instaling app without AppStore, Jailbreak or any warranty void itp.?

Tags: iphone, applications, install, cydia

I have a question. I'm developing an app for iOS. I don't have a subscription of Apple Developer Account(I'm thinking about buying that but I'm hesitating because I don't know whether my app will work or/and be published).

Are there any reliable and legal ways for my friend to install it on his iPhone **without jailbreak, AppStore or any warranty void itp.?** **Is Cydia Impactor safe under above conditions?** **Is Apple going to make trouble when they detect that an app was installed with this tool?**

Comment: There's 4 separate questions here, 3 alone are considered off topic - "will it void the warranty" , "is Cydia Impactor safe" and will "Apple make trouble."  We cannot answer those because we can't speak for Apple's actions or warranty coverage, only they can do that.  As for "being safe" that's an opinionated matter.  For assistance on writing good questions, please review our [Help Center How to Ask](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A person can deploy apps to their own iOS devices using Xcode without a developer account, and without breaking/modifying the OS.  All one needs is an Apple ID, and a Mac running a recent version of Xcode (7.3.1 or later).  This is an Apple approved method of installing apps (designed for educational purposes).  Xcode will generate the needed personal provisioning profiles automatically.

You can search for instructions online (here are a few examples: [Xcode 7 develop for iOS without developer account](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206123/xcode-7-develop-for-ios-without-developer-account) and http://blog.ionicframework.com/deploying-to-a-device-without-an-apple-developer-account/ )

Apps installed using personal provisioning will be time limited (expire in somewhere around one week to one month).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to pay for an Apple Developer Account in order to build an app. Only to publish it on the store. You can deploy test builds to your own personal device, or the simulator, for free.

Developing your own app without an Apple Developer Account has been a thing for a few years now.

Comment: Yes I know that. But how to install .ipa file on my friend's iPhone under above conditions (without jailbreak, AppStore and troubles during repair itp.)?

Comment: Because I know that I should generate provisioning profile and certificate but I need subscription of Developer Program in order to make it possible. I think that Cydia Impactor would do the job but he afraids that it will mess with his iPhone warranty

Comment: You have to create a "profile" for that application. Its the only way for it to be installed and accepted for use. Keep in mind since its not an Apple approved app, you may only get 7 days of testing with it. Thats my experience as an end user of personally designed apps.